# Make a flex item grow at hover without affecting the other flex elements, while keep box heights equivalent when not hovered

Tags: html, css

I have box elements in a flex container. I want the paragraph in a box to display when hovering over the box. However, the hovered box makes the other boxes grow too. Is there a way to avoid affecting the other boxes when hovering one box? 
I would try: *align-items:flex-start*, but I want the boxes to be equivalent in height when they are not hovered. 
So *align-items:flex-start* does not keep the boxes' height equivalent when they are not hovered. 
I want the box to enlarge when hovered without affecting the other boxes and turn back to the equivalent height when not hovered.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/lemour-sudo/pen/yLMQOpE

```css
.container > * {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 3em 10em;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
.box:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam tenetur amet dignissimos, accusantium molestias tempora!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 2</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptatum labore totam natus illo, magni inventore cupiditate hic omnis ipsam vero nobis enim dicta perferendis facilis tenetur quaerat! Voluptas, voluptatum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You better use a grid for this

Answer (score 1):

May be setting flex-start on hover of the container?

```css
.container > * {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 3em 10em;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

.container:hover {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  border: solid 3px red;
}
.box:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam tenetur amet dignissimos, accusantium molestias tempora!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 2 bigger than 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptatum labore totam natus illo, magni inventore cupiditate hic omnis ipsam vero nobis enim dicta perferendis facilis tenetur quaerat! Voluptas, voluptatum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution, with different heights in the initial state

```css
.container > * {
  width: 25em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 3em 10em;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

.container:hover {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  border: solid 3px red;
  height: fit-content;
}
.box:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam tenetur amet dignissimos, accusantium molestias tempora!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box 2 bigger than 1</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto voluptatum labore totam natus illo, magni inventore cupiditate hic omnis ipsam vero nobis enim dicta perferendis facilis tenetur quaerat! Voluptas, voluptatum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hover works. However, the cards are not the same height, if one contains more content than the other, initially. I would like them to have same height when not hovered even when one contains more content. But let the hovered card expand without affecting the other.

Comment: I don't understand your comment "are not the same height, if one ..." I have edited the snippet, to make one bigger, and they are the same height for me.

Comment: My mistake. I was not aware that I had not updated the code in my question. I wanted the boxes to have different amounts of content initially when not hovered. Thanks.

Comment: Added another snippet

Comment: This is what I meant. Is it possible to keep them at the same height initially but only let the hovered box grow without affecting the other?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how to do what you want but I think this way is better. It's more customizable. I agree with **vals** answer but If you don't want to make the container to grow all the way down this way is better.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.con {
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.item {
    border: 3px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.text-con {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: cadetblue;
}

.item:hover .text-con {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="con">
        <div class="item">
            <h1>box1</h1>
            <div class="text-con">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minus consequatur similique quas excepturi dignissimos optio nulla possimus</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>box2</h1>
            <div class="text-con">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minus consequatur similique quas excepturi dignissimos optio nulla possimus</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>box3</h1>
            <div class="text-con">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis minus consequatur similique quas excepturi dignissimos optio nulla possimus</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hovering works. I was hoping that the cards would automatically have equivalent heights (without explicitly specifying the height) initially when not hovered.